# Oracle - Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL)

Tags: java, oracle, jndi

I am using oracle database and JNDI connection to access it.

I have `addShutdownHook` that runs before the spring context destroyed, my requirement is to save the in-memory cached data in the database before application shutdown. The `addShutdownHook` is working fine but when it triggers the JNDI connections already closed and no more database connection is available and it throws below error:

`Sql Failed to execute: SHUTDOWN because Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-173]`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        log.info("Application shutting down, saving the API Event Log data to the database...")
        apiEventLogCacheService.saveAPIEventLogCacheToDB();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Not sure I understand this.  How does the db "save the in-memory cached data"?  DML changes are either committed or rolledback.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I guess OP wants to flush all modified data that is stored as in-memory cache to database before shutting down application

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I am using Spring.

Comment: Then you can extend `DisposableBean` and do all that stuff inside `destroy()` method.

Comment: @Ivan Same thing I am doing with ```addShutdownHook``` but I get this errer:

```Sql Failed to execute: SHUTDOWN because Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-173]```